# How to install nerfstudio on vast.ai

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytorch, anaconda

I am trying to install nerfstudio on ubuntu 18.04 via vast.ai
Conda and torch installed without any issues. The problem is with tinycudann

installation guide:
https://docs.nerf.studio/en/latest/quickstart/installation.html

below my errors:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/NVlabs/tiny-cuda-nn/#subdirectory=bindings/torch
  Cloning https://github.com/NVlabs/tiny-cuda-nn/ to /tmp/pip-req-build-s8v5l299
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/NVlabs/tiny-cuda-nn/ /tmp/pip-req-build-s8v5l299
  Resolved https://github.com/NVlabs/tiny-cuda-nn/ to commit a77dc53ed770dd8ea6f78951d5febe175d0045e9
  Running command git submodule update --init --recursive -q
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  _ python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  _ exit code: 1
  __> [9 lines of output]
      /root/miniconda3/envs/nerfstudio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:88: UserWarning: CUDA initialization: Unexpected error from cudaGetDeviceCount(). Did you run some cuda functions before calling NumCudaDevices() that might have already set an error? Error 803: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination (Triggered internally at ../c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:109.)
        return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-req-build-s8v5l299/bindings/torch/setup.py", line 49, in <module>
          raise EnvironmentError("Unknown compute capability. Specify the target compute capabilities in the TCNN_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES environment variable or install PyTorch with the CUDA backend to detect it automatically.")
      OSError: Unknown compute capability. Specify the target compute capabilities in the TCNN_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES environment variable or install PyTorch with the CUDA backend to detect it automatically.
      Building PyTorch extension for tiny-cuda-nn version 1.7
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

_ Encountered error while generating package metadata.
__> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

thanks for help in advance!